# Java - taking multiple paths as command line arguments whitespace issue

Tags: java, command-line, path, whitespace

Let's say I want to pass the following paths on the command line:

```
Path a: C:\example a\test
Path b: C:\example b\test\

java -jar myjar.jar C:\example a\test C:\example b\test\
```

Java splits arguments using whitespace, so we would end up with an args array like this:

```
arr[0] = C:\example
arr[1] = a\test
arr[2] = C:\example
arr[3] = b\test\
```

But if we also want to accept non-absolute paths, so supplying "`\test`" will cause the program to accept that as `<parent directory>\test`.

This gives a lot of problems and is much more complicated than it first appears. How do we tell Java that "`a\test`" is actually a part of "`C:\example a\test`" rather than "`<parent directory>\a\test`"?

Comment: Enclose the paths in quotes.

Comment: Did you try surrounding the path in quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes:

```
java -jar myjar.jar "C:\example a\test" "C:\example b\test\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a canonical file and extract the absolute name from it:

```
try {
    File file = (new File(arr[0])).getCanonicalFile();
    arr[0] = file.getAbsolutePath();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

This way you can compare them.